# Listing possibilities of a group based on some hints

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm trying to list all the possibilities for a group given the following conditions:
$G$ is of odd order, non-cyclic, contains no element of order $2$, and contains an element of order greater than $6$. Also the order of $G$ divides $120$.

My first reaction was to look at the permutation groups, but it seems they all contain an element of order $2$. Any hints are appreciated (please no full solutions!)

Comment: **Hint :** Show that the order of $G$ is necessarily $15$. (and also, notice that the conditions "$G$ has an odd order" and "$G$ does not contain any element of order $2$" are redundant).

Comment: The only group of order $15$ is cyclic, @TheSilverDoe.

Comment: Permutation groups and symmetric groups are different things; you mean the latter, right?

Comment: @Shaun Indeed, I was not clear. I wanted the OP to see that the fact that the order divides $120$ and that $G$ contains an element of order $\geq 6$ and no element of order $2$ *implies* that the order is $15$. And obviously it remains to use the non-cyclicity property. Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 2):

By Lagrange's Theorem, we know the order of an element of $G$ divides the order of $G.$

Since $G$ has odd order, we know $G$ has no elements of even order. Furthermore, since $G$ has an element of order $n > 6$, we know that $G$ is divisible by some odd integer $n > 6.$

So, $|G|$ is an odd divisor of $120$ which is divisible by some odd integer greater than 6. What must $|G|$ be?

Once you've done this, can you see where the non-cyclic condition comes in?

Comment: So it would |G| would be 15, but the only group of order 15 is cyclic, so perhaps I was wrong about the non-cyclic condition? I assumed that if it doesn't have an element of order 2, it would be non-cyclic.

Comment: @BoostMatch It certainly isn't true that a group without an element of order 2 is non-cyclic: $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ has only elements of order 1 and 3, but is cyclic. However, your question is still answerable if you keep the non-cyclic condition in: the answer is just "there are no such groups".